# How to Animate all visible icons in a listview all at once, on a button press

Tags: android, listview, animation

Im trying to implement an "edit mode" for a ListView. When the edit button is pressed I want all the star icons to turn into an "X" icon, with a crossfade animation.

[image]

I have seen a lot of examples on how to animate all of the icons in a Listview upon the drawing of the row (where the animation starts in the getView method of the adapter), but I want the animation to start at a later time, when the edit button is pressed.

I'm thinking I would set up the animation for each icon inside the getView, and put a reference to the view (or animation), then later when the button is pressed, I start the animation inside of a loop that traverses through the array.

What animation method should I use, and how should I hold a reference to it (or the view that needs to be animated)?

Bonus:
I'm not sure if this is something I should worry about, but I was thinking if I'm holding a reference to an array of objects as they get displayed to the screen, should I worry about the list growing too large and try to remove old objects as they move off the screen? if so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use the arraylist for all the list items that is for star icon, then you can give them a flag value with zero when populating the listview and when changing to cross icon you can change all the flag values in the arraylist to one and then animate the view in your adapter and notify the adapter after that. Another way is that you animate the view in your class file and notify your adapter.